# SQLAlchemy, update function add in other model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want to trigger Update function using SQLAlchemy, and I was able to get it working with using SQLAlchemy Text Function,

With the following:

```
UPDATE device SET status='Unavailable' FROM center WHERE center.id = device.center_id AND center.is_connected=false RETURNING device.id
```

However, I would like to make it as generic function, which I came up with something like this

```
from app.models import (
    Device,
    Center,
)

kwargs_filter = {}
kwargs_filter[Center.id] = Device.center_id
kwargs_filter[Center.is_connected] = False

kwargs_update = {}
kwargs_update[Device.status] = "Unavailable"
```

Then my db will trigger as:

```
await dbsession.execute(
    update(cls).
    where(kwargs_filter).
    values(kwargs_update).
    execution_options(synchronize_session="fetch")
)
await dbsession.commit()
obj = await cls.get(dbsession, id=id)
return obj
```

However, I am encountering error

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression for WHERE/HAVING role expected, got {<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x0000024A174FEB80>: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x0000024A1753A400>, <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x0000024A17508400>: False}.

Comment: Don't you want `where(**kwargs_filter)` to expand the arguments to keywords, instead of giving a dictionary directly?

Comment: Will that work? What is the difference between using double asterisk and using dict directly?

Comment: The reason I used kwargs_update and kwargs_filter is because both are suppose to be flexible and dynamic

Comment: Using the dict directly means the dict gets sent into the function, and the function has to handle dicts properly. Using `**kwargs_filter` means that the dicts gets expanded to arguments to the function instead, so effectively the code becomes `where(Center.id=Device.center_id)`. If you want these to be included as `Center.id == Device.center_id`, you can do `params = [], params.append(Center.id == Device.center_id), ...,` and then `where(*params)`.

Comment: Hi, yes, right after switching to kwargs, my code work.

Thank you